# Take the result of previous command safely : Batch (Wait,Sleep,Ping etc..)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, imacros

I am trying to create a batch file which is doing these things :

1. move some folder
2. call another batch file
3. copy the result of batch file to clipboard
4. run the imacros (imacros will use the clipboard)

So the important thing is I have to be sure for every step that it is completed. Because every step is attached together.

My question is how can I do that ? I read something about SLEEP, PING, TIMEOUT, PAUSE etc.. But I cannot know very much prons and cons. Could someone give some tips about these commands or which should i use for safe programming ?

Not : I am working on windows xp and windows server 2008

And here is my **batch code** :

```
@echo off

set cwd=D:\workset\xx\yyy\
set wp=D:\workset\xx\yyyy\zzzzz\

:: ensure folder exist
mkdir %cwd% > nul 2>&1
mkdir %wp%\done > nul 2>&1

d:
cd %wp%

:export

::echo tidy folder %wp%

for %%i in (xx_to_yy*.zip) do (
  move "%%i" "done\%%i"
)

echo call %cwd%aaa_bbb_export.bat
call %cwd%aaa_bbb_export.bat 5555 

@echo off

for %%i in (xx_to_yy*.zip) do (
  echo %wp%%%i | clip
  move "%%i" "done\%%i"
)

@echo off

:finish

start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  http://www.google.com
ping 127.1.1.1
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"   imacros://run/?m=yyy.iim
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `pause` and `echo` command is a great way to debug a piece of scrip in batch.

Simply add:

```
Echo Task Complete: [Description] : Continue ?&>nul pause
```

At the end of every task. That way, you can check if everythings fine before giving the all clear for you batch file to continue. Later on, you'll learn to do error checking in batch files, in which case you could do something similar with an error message and include soloutions as options.

### Edit:

If you wish to automate the script, so that it doesn't need user input, and instead attempts to check ikf an error occured you could either:

- Check manualy, that is 1: check if folder has moved, 2: check if other batch file did what it needed (create new files etc.) 3: check if clipboard has suffiecent lines to be result of batch files (maybe clear it at the start) and lastly, check if imacros did what was needed
- Check if commands were succeful. (redirec errors to a text file and then see if they were any.

Since, I don't know exactly what you are doing, I can only help you wit case 2 (though 1 would be better). You redirect the errors as so:

```
command [parameters] 2>>errors.log
```

And at the end of every section:

```
set /p error=<errors.log
if defined error (
Echo An Error Occured : Last Step == [Step Description]
ECHO ----------  RUN : %Date% %Time%  ----------
type errors.log >> error-log.txt
del errors.log
if "%~1"=="RESTART" (
Echo Error Occured Two Times in a Row . . .
Echo Exiting in 20 seconds . . .
Exit /b 9
)
Echo Restarting procedure in 60 seconds . . .
sleep 60
Start %~f0 "RESTART"
Exit
)
```

The above code will check if there were any errors, add them to a log called error-log.txt. If there is an error, it will restart and if there is an error again, it will exit. There will be a small pause before either of these events, incase you want to cancel it (simply close)

Hope you found this helpful,

Mona.

Comment: But I think the pause command will stop my script and want from me to press some key, I want to do this script whole automize. So the script should start and finish without any intervention. So what is your opinion on this time ?

Answer (score 0):

First option is, after each "critical" command, check for errorlevel

```
copy someThing someWhere
if errorlevel 1 (
    rem something goes bad
    goto somewhereToHandleIt
)
```

Alternatively, you can add code to check that the operation was sucessful, testing everything is where it is supossed to be. But first option is usually better. Trust the system, it will do the work and report when problems found.

Comment: @Monacraft: You are right, AND sometimes the errorlevel exists and is inaccesible, BUT almost all commands change the errorlevel. All usual file operation commands change errorlevel. And for each that not, output can be filtered/parsed to generate an errorlevel or processed to test for error condition. And, just my opinion, except for some critical cases, or when the existence of the error can be prevented, asking the system to do something and testing the presence of error is the most practical way of coding batch files.